# visual studio express 2015 for windows desktop hangs during installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-express

I am trying to install Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop on my 64 bit Windows 8.1 ASUS laptop.  During the installation process, the installer gets stuck on Applying the Windows Software Development Kit.  I have tried and tried several times to download and install but with no luck.  I also made sure I had the latest windows updates that are required for the install, BTW.  Please help.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the full Community Edition of 2015? https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Comment: No.  I guess not.  For whatever reason, I thought I read that Community was more for developing applications for devices other than the desktop.  After re-reading its description, I will give it a shot and let you know if it works or if I still have the same problem.  Thanks!